# Is the following an undefined behavior? i = func(i)

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

I know that `i=i++;` is an undefined behavior, because `i` is changed twice before the sequence point `;`.

But I don't know if the compiler guarantees the case as below is not an undefined behavior:

```
int func(int &i)
{
    i++;
    return i;
}

int i = 1;
i = func(i);
```

Comment: what the compiler tells ?

Comment: @tristan typically, the compiler does not tell anything about UB.

Comment: gcc has '-Wsequence-point' option

Comment: @tristan: In general case it is impossible to detect violation of sequencing rules (since it might require full understanding of aliasing picture). So, in order to use `-Wsequence-point` you need a certain level of proficiency to know what to expect and what not to expect in each particular case. For which reason a "just try it" kind of suggestion does not always work well for everyone.

Comment: @tristan The gcc manual: "Some more complicated cases are not diagnosed by this option, and it may give an occasional false positive result".

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Firstly, modern C++ has switched from the old (inadequate) concept of "sequence points" to the new concept of "sequencing" (i.e. "sequenced before", "sequenced after"). While `i = i++` is still undefined, `i = ++i` is actually perfectly defined now. Sequencing rules in many lvalue-returning operators were reworked.

Secondly, your version is safe under the old specification as well as under the new one. The modification of `i` inside the function is safely "isolated" from the assignment to `i` outside. In the classic specification sequence points at the beginning and at the end of the function safely separated the modifications (and reads) of `i` from each other. The new sequencing rules preserve the same level of protection as well.

An example that illustrates the protection provided by a function call might look as follows

```
int inc(int &i) { return i++; }
...
int i = 1;

int r1 = i++ * i++ * i++;          
// Undefined behavior because of multiple unsequenced side effects
// applied to the same variable

int r2 = inc(i) * inc(i) + inc(i);
// No UB, but order of evaluation is unspecified. Since the result 
// depends on the order of evaluation, it is unspecified

int r3 = inc(i) + inc(i) + inc(i); 
// Perfectly defined result. Order of evaluation is still unspecified, 
// but the result does not depend on it
```

Comment: "The modification of i inside the function is safely "isolated" from the assignment to i outside." What if the compiler inlines the function? Or does the potential for UB mean the compiler won't inline this specific case?

Comment: @JAB: Inlining does not in any way alter the sequencing semantics (or any other semantics) of a function call. The compiler is free to inline anything it wants at any time, but the resultant code must fully preserve the original abstract semantics. I.e. the behavior of inlined call must be the same as behavior of non-inlined call. There's nothing in this case to prevent the compiler from inlining. But the compiler must remember that the inlined version shall fully preserve the behavior of non-inlined one.

Comment: Well that's good, given that I've taken advantage of that sort of behavior in the past.